# instrument symbols for a 2008 GMC w5500

Tags: gmc, instrument-cluster

Just bought this truck but have no manual for it. Just wondering if anyone knows where I can get one, or information for a website where I could go to get information on symbol meanings for the instrument panel

Comment: Have you tried signing up on the GMC owners section of their website? https://my.gmc.com/home

Answer (score 1):

Your W5500 is produced by Isuzu and should be the same as their N-Series trucks. Here are the dash lights for a [2007 Isuzu N-Series](https://www.isuzucv.com/en/app/site/pdf?file=manuals/2007_N_Series_Diesel_NPR.pdf):

[image]

[image]

Comment: thanks, Paulster2 really clears up a lot. thanks for the link